# How to get data from objected created in other class in new class - java

Tags: java, android, oop, object

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ShareData SD = new ShareData();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SD.set_numb(5);
    }

    //  when button clicked
    public void noviEkran(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,klasaB.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}




public class ShareData {

    private int number;

    public ShareData(){
        this.number=0;
    }
    public void set_numb(int num){
        number = num;
    }
    public int get_numb(){
        return number;
    }
}


public class klasaB extends Activity{

    ShareData sd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int i =sd.get_numb();
        System.out.println("Saved numb:" + i);
    }

}
```

My question is, if i declare object in 1st class, and set its parameter number to 5, how to acces this number from other class because now my apk crashes when reading  " int i =sd.get_numb(); " in class "klasaB".
Any suggestion how to make this work?
ps: i dont want to use static variables, or putExtra with Intents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a singleton class

Declare an instance in `ShareData` class:

`public class ShareData {
private static ShareData sdInstance = null;
...}`

add this method in ShareData class:

```
public static ShareData getInstance(){
    if(sdInstance == null){
        sdInstance = new ShareData();
    }
    return sdInstance;
}
```

To get same object in other classes , use this

`ShareData sd = ShareData.getInstance();`

now you will receive same `sd.get_numb()`

Comment: Tnx, but now i dont get number 5 as output, i get number 0, any suggestion why ?

Comment: First you have to set_number in say `classA` then 
use 
`ShareData sd = ShareData.getInstance();`
`sd.get_numb()`
in class B

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public ShareData SD = new ShareData();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SD.set_numb(5);

    }
    //  when button clicked
    public void noviEkran(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,klasaB.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
} still get 0  :S :S :S

Comment: don't do `public ShareData SD = new ShareData()`
create new objects using `ShareData SD = ShareData.getInstance();`

Answer (score 1):

If data is simple/primitive then use Intent to pass data from one activity to another. That is what Intent is for.

If it is not (some sort of complex data structure or object), I would extend Application, by making a custom sub class. Application class (as the name implies) is accessible to all Activities, even when app transitions from one to another. Below is a very simple example, just to show you the idea. You can modify/adjust that to your needs.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
   private X x;

   public static void setX(X x) { ... }
   public static X getX() { ... }
}
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    ...
    MyApplication.setX(x);

}
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    ...
    X x = MyApplication.getX();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have mixed up Activity/MainActivity/AppCombatActivity inheritance... I suspect that the reason you are seeing the error -- by the way, please look into "how to ask" and include a bit more information next time -- is that sd in klasaB is never initialized.

MainActivity.SD will hold that 5 after *its* onCreate(), whereas klasaB.sd is never set to anything.

Comment: Now i set in klasaB     MainActivity main;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int i = main.SD.get_numb();

        System.out.println("Saved numb:" + i);   , the error is in line main.SD.get_numb(); shouldn't it work like this ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you were more specific about what the error is...

Here, it doesn't look like klasaB.main is ever instantiated.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at com.example.ivica.optest.klasaB.onCreate(klasaB.java:19) ->  int i = main.SD.get_numb(); , how do you mean klasaB.main is never instantieted? Am i not with MainActivity main able to get variables from MainActivity as the SD ?

Comment: It's important to understand what's happening here... Instantiation is when you create an individual instance of a class -- not declare a variable name! If you declare a variable but do not instantiate before using it, the program will try to use your variable to reference an instance, but the variable will still reference `null`. 

Is that clear(er)?

Answer (score 0):

You never reference or instantiate SD in class B. To get the data to ClassB you will need to set the data as an extra in the intent. Most classes cannot be sent in the intent, so for your case you should pass the primitive types of the object, then create the object.

```
//  when button clicked
public void noviEkran(View view){
Intent i = new Intent(this,klasaB.class);
i.putExtra("TAG", SD.get_num());
startActivity(i);
```

And then in Class B

```
ShareData SD = new ShareData();
SD.set_num(getIntent.getIntExtra("TAG", 0);
```

Comment: This is oke, but i dont want to do it like this. How to get the number with  int i = main.SD.get_numb(); in klasaB with declared at start MainActivtiy main;

Answer (score 0):

You can access your class object either using implements [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) or [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

1.Implement serializable into your ShareData class

```
public class ShareData implements Serializable{

    private int number;

    public ShareData(){
        this.number=0;
    }
    public void set_numb(int num){
        number = num;
    }
    public int get_numb(){
        return number;
    }
}
```

2.create object of SharedData and share with intent to classB

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public ShareData SD = new ShareData();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SD.set_numb(5);
}

//  when button clicked
public void noviEkran(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,klasaB.class);
    i.putExtras("key", SD)
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

3.Access in classB

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ShareData sd = (ShareData)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key").
    System.out.println("Saved numb:" + sd.get_num());
}
```

Comment: This is cool, is there another way to get the data without Intents, coz if i have lets say 10 variables, and always sendingd them trought activitys,  is there a way to have a class with constructor, setter and getter and changing and retrivig data from other classes as i need, For example, if i have classA, there i make an object from classB, set its name to "John", and in classC i  use get_name from the objected created in classA?

Comment: Using implementation of Serializable into classB, you can easily share it between two activities. Just use putExtra to send and access it with getIntent by key e.g ShareData sd = (ShareData) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key") or you can share classB objcet using declared as static